# Assigning Objects to Many-to-many relationships - Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a django project where I have a list with checkboxes, to select and assign students to teachers.
I have attached my code below - I am getting no errors, but it doesn't seem to be assigning the student to the "students" many-to-many field in my "teachers" model.

I have a GET function that is called earlier to select the teacher, then it is meant to pull that GET record and assign the student to that teacher.

Any ideas?

Views.py

```
        if 'assign_student' in request.POST:
            form = StudentForm(request.POST)
            selected = request.GET['select_teacher']
            selected_teacher = Teacher.objects.all().filter(pk=selected)[0]
            if form.is_valid():
                student_selected = request.POST('assign_student')
                student = Student.objects.all().filter(pk=student_selected)[0]
                selected_teacher.students.add(student)
```

Template.html

```
    <div class="student-list">       
        {% for instance in all_students %}
        <div class="input-group" style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">
            <div class="item-details">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <form method="POST" class="form-group" name="assign_student">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <input onChange="this.form.submit()" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value={{ instance.pk }} id="flexCheckDefault" name="assign_student">
                    </form>
                    <p>
                        <b>{{ instance.fullname }}</b>
                        <br>
                        {{ instance.homeschool }} - {{ instance.schoolclass }} Class
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=10000,verbose_name='Full Name')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=10000,verbose_name='First Name')
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=10000,verbose_name='Last Name')
    school = ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='School')
    creationuser = ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        principal = 'principal'
        classroomteacher = 'classroom teacher'
        assistantprincipal = 'assistant principal'

    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=10000,
        choices=Role.choices,
        verbose_name='Role',
    )

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email Address')

    def __str__(self):
         return self.fullname
```

Comment: There is only one student in `add` because you used `[0]` in the filter. So just change the `add` to: `selected_teacher.students.add(student)` (remove the *)

Comment: Thanks @bdbd I just changed it, and it still doesnt seem to be adding that student to the relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah im silly!

I fixed it, I was trying to get a "if form.is_valid()" when i'm not posting a full form - removed that and all is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because you are using queries by using filters etc. Thus you are returned a query set instead of an object.
Instead you should use the `get_object_or_404()`.

Furthermore, you are saving the data for the session and not in the database. You should use `students.save()` to save it in the DB.

You can do something like this

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

        if 'assign_student' in request.POST:
            form = StudentForm(request.POST)
            selected = request.GET['select_teacher']
            selected_teacher = get_object_or_404(Teacher, pk=selected)
            if form.is_valid():
                student_selected = request.POST('assign_student')
                student = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=student_selected)
                selected_teacher.students.add(student)
                selected_teacher.save() #saving the teacher model object
                selected_teacher.students.save() #saving the student model object
```

Comment: Great, reply, thankyou. 
Although sadly that still didnt work. I am fairly sure with me adding the [0] at the end of the filter it returns an item rather than a queryset, but yes your way is nicer.

But I tried mirroring your supplied code, and still we get no results

Comment: I just put some "prints" in each part of the form - it looks like it isnt getting past the "if form.is_valid()", hmm.